# Microsoft open R fatal error when trying to change number of core for multithread processing

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I am using window 10 pro and downloaded Microsoft open R to run in rstudio. open R has built-in multithread processing I want to try out.

I tried command setMKLthreads(2). then R shows fatal error and needs to restart.

when I run the getMKLthreads() R is running fine

> getMKLthreads()
>   [1] 8

only when I want to change the number of cores R collapse.

Please advise

Comment: I followed exact instruction on open R site https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. RStudio Version 1.2.1335, MRO 3.5.3. Win10/64bit. setMKLthreads() crashes R everytime. If I run MRO without RSudio, the command runs OK.